# How to get value from XML in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures

Can you all help me for this problem?
I want to get value from following XML in sql stored procedure. I don't get vlaue if 'xsi:type="ActiveDirectoryItem"' is in tag 'anyType', and 'ActiveDirectoryItems' tag is also with URLs. How can i do to get only values?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ActiveDirectoryItems xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Items>
<anyType xsi:type="ActiveDirectoryItem">
  <FirstName /> 
  <MiddleInitial /> 
  <LastName />
  <DisplayName>Migrate-group</DisplayName> 
  <UserPrincipalName /> 
  <PostalAddress /> 
  <ResidentialAddress />
  <Title />
  <HomePhone />
  <OfficePhone />
  <Mobile />   
  <Fax /> 
  <Email>Migrate-group@gmail.com</Email> 
  <Url /> 
  <AccountName>Migrate-group</AccountName> 
  <DistinguishedName /> 
  <IsAccountActive>false</IsAccountActive> 
  <ManagedBy /> 
  <Manager /> 
  <CompareType>0</CompareType> 
  <Description /> 
  <Department /> 
  <Company /> 
  <Type /> 
  </anyType>
  </Items>
 <GlobalCatalog /> 
 </ActiveDirectoryItems>
```

The format i want to get is as the following:

```
DisplayName         Email                          Account Name
Migrate-group       Migrate-group@gmail.com     Migrate-group
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `value` keyword

Example:

```
DECLARE @MyXml XML = '<Root><SomeData>100</SomeData></Root>'

DECLARE @Something INT
SELECT @Something = @MyXml.value('(//Root/SomeData)[1]', 'INT')
```

Comment: thanks for comment. i tried it. But it doesn't work if 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"' is in <ActiveDirectoryItem> tag.